# How to translate a Tab name and a TextField?

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to translate a `Tab` and a `TextField` but it is not translating at the moment. Current setup as per below:

Locale is set in `_config.php` - I have flushed.

```
i18n::set_locale('de_DE');
```

**mysite/lang/de.yml**

```
de:
  Page:
    FULLNAME: 'Testing this'
    CONTACTDETAILS: 'Root.Trying to change to this text'
```

**Page.php**

```
<?php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $db = array(
        'FullName' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldsToTab(_t('Page.CONTACTDETAILS', 'Root.ContactDetails'), array(
            TextField::create('FullName', _t('Page.FULLNAME', 'Full Name'))
        ));
        return $fields;
    }

}
```

But the text is not being translated it just shows in English. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CMS uses the currently logged in user's `Locale` field for translations afaik. You can change a user's locale to `de_DE` (whereupon your translations should work) by going to `Security`, selecting the user, and changing `Interface Language` to `German (Germany)`.

It's also possible to set the locale inside your `getCMSFields` if you only want the fields in there to get translated:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $oldLocale = i18n::get_locale();
    i18n::set_locale('de_DE');
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldsToTab(_t('Page.CONTACTDETAILS', 'Root.ContactDetails'), array(
        TextField::create('FullName', _t('Page.FULLNAME', 'Full Name'))
    ));
    i18n::set_locale($oldLocale);
    return $fields;
}
```

The `Locale` of new users created through the CMS will be set based on the `Locale` of the user that is creating them.

Comment: Ah yes, changed the user's Interface Language as you stated and it worked. I did have to add 'Root.' to my yml file so it would work for the tab as it was throwing an error. e.g `CONTACTDETAILS: 'Root.Trying to change to this text'` - Thank you :)

Comment: Good practice could be to leave out 'Root.' from the yml files and do this instead: `$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.' . _t('Page.CONTACTDETAILS', 'Contact details'), [...]`